# Meta-analysis with only p-values

Tags: r, meta-analysis, combining-p-values, systematic-review

I am doing a systematic review on the risk factors that predict infection after liver and pancreatic surgery.  These risk factors include parameters like age, sex, smoking, pre-operative chemo etc.

I have a number of studies but not all report their findings in the same way, so I am having trouble doing the meta-analysis.  Some of the studies only report a p-value.  Beyond simply counting the number of studies that have significant P-values for each risk factor, is there another way to derive an overall p-value for each risk factor?

Comment: Do you know the direction of the effect?

Comment: You can work back from a p-value to a standardized difference and variance, if you know the sample size (and the direction).

Comment: I do know the direction of the effect and sample size.

Comment: Here is a worked example using R: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:assembling_data_smd

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to calculate an overall $p$-value: Edgington's method, Fisher's, Lancaster's, Stouffer, Tippett's and several others. They all have their advantages and disadvantages. Since you have tagged this R you may be interested to read the vignettes for the metap package available from CRAN which contains some guidance on the choice. It is too long to include here.

Disclaimer: I am the author of that package. There are other packages available, see the [CRAN Task View on MetaAnalysis](https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=MetaAnalysis) for details (I maintain that too).